# Change Black Macbook Pro screen to something cool when music is playing?

Tags: macbook-pro

When I am playing music on my Macbook Pro and don't touch the computer for a while, the screen goes black and the music is still playing. How do I change the black screen to something cool that goes with the music?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With iTunes in foreground, either press <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>T</kbd> or select View > Visualizer, choose the animation, and select View > Show Visualizer.

The visual effect will change with the music: enjoy!

Comment: iTunes has [several options](http://cl.ly/g65I) for visualizers which you might want to look at.

Comment: I've noticed that the "iTunes Visualizer" view is often/sometimes tweaked in iTunes updates so be sure to check that out.

Answer (score 1):

On your Mac, open up `System Preferences`, then:

- Select `Screen Saver` in the menu bar
- Scroll down in the left-hand gallery and choose `iTunes Artwork`
- In the bottom-left, you can choose how long after you stop interacting with the computer that you want the screen saver to start by clicking the dropdown labeled `Start After:`.

**This basically has your computer, instead of going to a black screen after inactivity, display your iTunes album covers, from which you can play these albums by simply clicking on their respective covers.**